# self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK) AssertionError: 404 != 200

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, automated-tests, python-3.9

---

This is were the error comes from

```
def test_single_status_retrieve(self):
            serializer_data = ProfileStatusSerializer(instance=self.status).data
            response = self.client.get(reverse("status-detail", kwargs={"pk": 1}))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
            response_data = json.loads(response.content)
            self.assertEqual(serializer_data, response_data)
```

It seems like the error is coming from somewhere else.

Here is my setUp

```
def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="test2",
                                            password="change123",
                                            )
        self.status = ProfileStatus.objects.create(user_profile=self.user.profile, 
                                                    status_content="status test")                             
        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
        self.api_authentication()
```

here is **urls.py** file

```
from django.db import router
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from profiles.api.views import (AvatarUpdateView,
                                ProfileViewSet, 
                                ProfileStatusViewSet,
                                )

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"profiles", ProfileViewSet)
router.register(r"status", ProfileStatusViewSet, basename="status")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
    path("avatar/", AvatarUpdateView.as_view(), name="avatar-update"),
]
```

**This is what I got when I ran the test**

> (ProjectName) bash-3.2$ **python3 manage.py test** Creating test database for alias 'default'... System check identified no issues (0
> silenced). F.........
> ================================================================= FAIL: test_single_status_retrieve
> (profiles.tests.ProfileStatusViewSetTestCase)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "path.../ProjectName/src/profiles/tests.py", line 101, in
> test_single_status_retrieve
> self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK) AssertionError: 404 != 200
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 10 tests in 1.362s
>
> FAILED (failures=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Comment: The record may not exists. Have you inserted a record with pk 1 in this test case ? May be in setUp() function ?

Comment: Try printing `response.content` to see what is going on within the response.

Comment: @EliasPrado Where in the code do I print this? I have tried printing in the last line, but it doesn't show up, when I don't do any tab/space, I get an error **AttributeError: module 'django.http.response' has no attribute 'content'**

Comment: below the response: `print('RESPONSE ==>', response.content)`

Comment: Here it is **RESPONSE ==> b'{"detail":"Not found."}'**

Comment: Try applying the answer I have added. Drf needs the headers to be added to make some requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in this file

**Views.py** in folders profiles/api

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins, viewsets
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from profiles.api.permissions import IsOwnProfileOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from profiles.api.serializers import (ProfileAvatarSerializer,
                                      ProfileSerializer,
                                      ProfileStatusSerializer,
                                     )
from profiles.models import Profile, ProfileStatus


class AvatarUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileAvatarSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self):
        profile_object = self.request.user.profile
        return profile_object


class ProfileViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnProfileOrReadOnly]
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["city"]


class ProfileStatusViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileStatusSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ProfileStatus.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get("username", None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user_profile__user__username=username)
            return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user_profile = self.request.user.profile
        serializer.save(user_profile=user_profile)
```

Changed to

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins, viewsets
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from profiles.api.permissions import IsOwnProfileOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from profiles.api.serializers import (ProfileAvatarSerializer,
                                      ProfileSerializer,
                                      ProfileStatusSerializer,
                                     )
from profiles.models import Profile, ProfileStatus


class AvatarUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileAvatarSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self):
        profile_object = self.request.user.profile
        return profile_object


class ProfileViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnProfileOrReadOnly]
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["city"]


class ProfileStatusViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileStatusSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ProfileStatus.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get("username", None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user_profile__user__username=username)
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user_profile = self.request.user.profile
        serializer.save(user_profile=user_profile)
```

---

Hard to spot it, hint look at `return queryset` in `def get_queryset(self):`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the headers in drf for `change/create/delete` requests.
.

Also, you need to add the `app_name: your_app_name` within the url.py and place it within the reverse() url.

Like this.

1. Ulr for get request: `reverse('your_app_name:your_router_basename-list')`
2. Url for delte/change request:`reverse('your_app_name:your_router_basename-detail')`

Dont also forget that within the `response` you need to place: 1- the url, 2- the data and 3- the JSON format. With headers in case of create/delete/change requests.

Try this approach:

```
def test_single_status_retrieve(self):

    serializer_data = ProfileStatusSerializer(instance=self.status).data
    
    # HERE
    response = self.client.get(reverse("your_app_name:profile-detail", kwargs={"pk": 1}), serializer_data, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    response_data = json.loads(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(serializer_data, response_data)
```

Comment: I added it and saved, ran the test, but still got the same error **AssertionError: 404 != 200**. Here is the github link to the tutorial https://github.com/pymike00/The-Complete-Guide-To-DRF-and-VueJS/blob/master/05-DRF-LEVEL-THREE/profilesapi/profiles/tests.py

Comment: I've checked your url.py and it doenst have a basename for some routers and nor a app_name to reference in the reverse() method. So, in your url.py add and `app_name=your_app_name` and follow the answer I have added above.

Comment: I have 2 urls.py files, one in api folder and another one in profilesapi. Which one is it? The api folder is in the same folder where this code is, and profilesapi folder is outside of it, but in the project folder.

Comment: the one inside the app.

Comment: I'm not sure what to add in the urls.py file?

Comment: Have a look at this code. I have added the urls.py and tests.py for you to understand. the request to test comes from urls.py to tests.py https://pastebin.com/GY7QJLxz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233111/discussion-between-elias-prado-and-derekpk).